# Symfony / Api Platform - How to get data with a session parameter

Tags: php, api, symfony, entity, api-platform.com

I am making an app to manage accountnancy of 2 companies. I'm good with symfony and someone talked to me about API Platform (as I am using VueJS for the front part)

The trouble is that I would like to use API platform to manage my entities. I have an entity called "PAYMENT" in which I add the incomes and outcomes.

If I use the route /api/payments, I get all the payments in my DB, it is obvious. Now I'd like to do the same thing but only get the payments related to the company I'm logged with.

In my Payment entity, have a field "company" that is a ManyToOne relation to Company such as :

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Company::class, inversedBy="payments")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
* @Groups({"items:payments:get"})
*/
private $company;
```

How can I include for example a session variable ('company_id') to get only companies related payments ?

Or is there a way to get payments with a route such as : /api/companyName/payments

For more security I do not want to make a filter like /api/payments?company=VALUE to avoid the person managing the company 1 to get the data of the company 2.

Comment: Implement a custom [Data Extension](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/#custom-doctrine-orm-extension) that filters your `Payment` entities based on the current session `company_id`.

Comment: Hi @JeroenvanderLaan, thank you for your tip, seems interesting to work around.